# How to find out line number, procedure name in PL/SQL in case of an error

Tags: oracle, plsql, unique-constraint, ora-00001

I am using a D2k 6i form and getting the error on form from stored database(oracle9i) procedure ORA-00001:Unique constraint(.) violated but i m not able to trace out from which procedure it is coming.
can anybody help me regarding this

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, here is the solution the OP found:

> ok in D2k forms there is an ON-ERROR trigger where you can use the function DBMS_ERROR_TEXT to get the procedure,package name line number of the statement from where the error is coming

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this pattern after much research, head banging and gnashing of teeth:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_schema.package_name
IS

  PROCEDURE foo
  IS
  BEGIN
    -- Call stored procedures/functions that throw unhandled exceptions
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR! - '
        || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK
        || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);
  END foo;

END;
```

The `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK` function seems to give the error code and message, and `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE` seems to give an honest to goodness stack trace, complete with line numbers and stored procedure names in Oracle 10g at least.

I'm not sure if those functions are available in Oracle 9i. I couldn't find much information about this sort of thing even for Oracle 10g, so I thought I would at least post this answer since 9i is quite old (and so it 10g for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

Posting your exception with your question would give us a better idea of what you are confronted with.

Usually an exception will tell you the package and the line number within the error message.  From that, you can query the USER_SOURCE table:

```
SELECT text 
FROM user_source 
WHERE type = 'PACKAGE BODY' 
  AND name = 'myProcName' 
  AND line = [the line number];
```

It might be useful to know more about the context within which the error was triggered. For that you can use the `BETWEEN' operator:

```
SELECT text 
FROM user_source 
WHERE type = 'PACKAGE BODY' 
  AND name = 'myProcName' 
  AND line BETWEEN [the line number - 5] AND [the line number +5];
```

Comment: actually i wanted to find out the name of the procedure and line number from which the error is coming .The query provided by you is only useful when you know the procedure name ,packeage name .

Comment: @bhagwat - if you have found an answer then post it here at SO.  Be a teacher as well as student.

Comment: ok in D2k forms there is an ON-ERROR trigger where you can use the function DBMS_ERROR_TEXT to get the procedure,package name line number of the statement from where the error is coming